# 8-bit encoded file writing?

Tags: python, encoding

I want to write a file with one byte per character only, it's necessary because a bank make this to generate tickets...

My code is:

```
arquivo = os.path.join(request.folder,"uploads", "teste.txt")
texto = '01REMESSA01COBRANÇA       3007 ...'.decode("windows-1252")
text_file = open(arquivo, "w")
texto = texto.encode('ISO8859-1','ignore')
text_file.write(texto)
text_file.close()`
```

It generates '?' characters.

Comment: How do you know these are '?' characters? Are you sure you are looking at your output file in `ISO8859-1` encoding?

Comment: This is the output using encode 'mbcs'               '01REMESSA01COBRANÃ?A......'

Answer (score 0):

You are encoding your string twice, both of which are unnecessary. The fixed code looks like:

```
texto = '01REMESSA01COBRAN\N{LATIN CAPITAL LETTER C WITH CEDILLA}A  ...'
with open(arquivo, 'w', encoding='ISO-8859-1') as text_file:
    text_file.write(texto)
```

I am assuming you are using Python3 because your original string has a literal `Ç` in it which would not be allowed in Python2. All strings in Python3 are Unicode unless given a special prefix (such as `b'these are octets'`). In general you should keep strings in unicode as long as possible, in this case until you must write a byte-file.

To delay the encoding as late as can be, `open` allows an `encoding=` option. I like that is specifies the encoding of the *file* so if you are reading or writing it just does the right thing. This allows us to add

```
# confirm we read what we meant
print(open(arquivo, encoding='latin-1').read())
```

which just works. Note, `'ISO-8859-1'` and `'latin-1'` are the same encoding in Python; similarly `\N{CAPITAL...}` and `'Ç'` are also identical, the former is just far more visible for example purposes.

I consulted the [Python Unicode HOWTO](https://docs.python.org/3.4/howto/unicode.html) to make sure I remembered correctly. I recommend you read it. For reasons explained by Nick Coghalan's "[Processing Text Files in Python 3](http://python-notes.curiousefficiency.org/en/latest/python3/text_file_processing.html)" you should probably forget about cp1252.

Comment: I forgot, i'm using python 2.. because my system are running old version of CentOS and py2.. right i want to save the .txt file in ANSI codec, using windows break line, because my bank only allow this.. thanks at all

Comment: I need to generate the file with coding in the ANSI standard of windows, because face character has to occupy only one byte .. like when a file with notepad .. if I generate the same file with the string quoted, by notepad, It works fine for the api of the bank ..